# Is there a way to gracefully shutdown an ASP.NET WebApi?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am running a ASP.NET web application (4.72) on IIS.
Is there any way to gracefully shutdown the web api?

After restoring a database backup I want to shutdown the application or restart the machine.

Comment: Please define what you mean by gracefully. Other than something crashing, I would hope that all shutdowns would be graceful! Where do want to initate this shutdown and why? Your question doesn't contain enough information for anyone to be able to answer.

Comment: Graceful is a common term when talking about shutdowns and yes that means without crashing for me. I do not really understand what information is missing. Either it is possible to shutdown api or not? Maybe I should consider going the extra mile and workaround the need of shutting down the application..

Comment: @AvrohomYisroel `gracefully` is a very specific term. It doesn't need to be define and no, applications don't shutdown gracefully unless you put enough effort to make them do so

Comment: As a general rule, if the web site is running and has a live connection to the database, then I doubt VERY much that you can restore the database while the site is running. As pointed out, you need to halt/stop the web site. You can then do the database restore, and then restart the site. Of course, this type of operation will be a rare once every 5 years kind of thing, so I see VERY little reason why such a process would be automated??? If you need to update the database (and hopefully NOT do a full restore, then of course you can run/have/should/use some scripts that update the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You stop the IIS app pool for the application. You can do this either manually in IIS Manager, or programatically with the [`Stop-WebAppPool`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/webadministration/stop-webapppool) PowerShell cmdlet. It will allow any in-progress requests to finish, then shut down.

If your application needs to do anything before shutting down, you can define the `Application_End` event in Global.asax:

```
public void Application_End() {
   //Wrap up
}
```